# Oracle apex home page the checksum computed did not match the checksum passed into the show procedure

Tags: oracle, session, oracle-apex, checksum

I have this apex application where the logout url redirects you on the Home page that is created by apex when you first create the application.
On that page we have 3 buttons, 1 that takes you to the login page, 1 to register, and 1 to the real home page of the application in case the page is reached when the user is already logged in(which should normally not happen).
The issue is now when the session expires, the user is redirected to this Home Page as the logout URL is set to point to the Home Page, but this does not happen as the user gets an error:

```
apex_error_code: APEX.SESSION_STATE.SSP_VIOLATION2_FOR_DEVELOPERS
original message: The checksum computed on the request, clear cache, argument names, and argument values (,3420 [xxxxxxxxx]) did not match the checksum passed into the show procedure (yyyyyyyyy).
```

Note: End-users get a different error message.

I checked the home page and the configuration is as below:

The printscreen of configuration:

[image]

I am new to apex and don't understand really well how this should work.

Comment: I am guessing that when a session times out, the checksum for the target page expires.  You may need to just turn off "Page Access Protection" to not be "Arguments Must Have Checksum" -- that is not terribly useful for a "Authentication" type of "Page Is Public."